# sql fetching data from joins and get result as assosiative array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
 TABLE WORKSHOPS
--------------------------------
id|course_id|country_id|city_id|
--------------------------------
1 |  5      |    1     |   2   |
--------------------------------
2 |  5      |    1     |   4   |
--------------------------------
3 |  5      |    2     |   5   |
--------------------------------
```

```
TABLE WORKSHOP_DATES
----------------------------------------
id|start_date | end_date | workshop_id |
----------------------------------------
1 |2014-11-05 |2014-11-06|      1      |
----------------------------------------
2 |2014-11-28 |2014-11-29|      1      |
----------------------------------------
3 |2014-11-28 |2014-11-30|      1      |
----------------------------------------
```

I am using the following query

```
$this->db->select("$this->_table.*, $_courses_table.name as course, $_countries_table.name as country, $_cities_table.name as city, $_workshop_dates_table.id as workshop_dates_id, $_workshop_dates_table.start_date as start_date, $_workshop_dates_table.end_date as end_date");


    $this->db->join("$_courses_table", "$_courses_table.id = $this->_table.ktw_course_id");
    $this->db->join("$_countries_table", "$_countries_table.id = $this->_table.ktw_country_id");
    $this->db->join("$_cities_table", "$_cities_table.id = $this->_table.ktw_city_id");
    $this->db->join("$_workshop_dates_table", "$_workshop_dates_table.ktw_workshop_id = $this->_table.id");        
    $this->db->where('ktw_course_id', $course_id);

    $this->db->group_by("$_workshop_dates_table.ktw_workshop_id");
    $this->db->order_by('start_date', 'ASC');

    return  $this->db->get($this->_table);
```

But the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [price] => 1300
            [discount] => 13
            [early_bird_date] => 2014-12-30
            [timing] => 
            [batch] => 
            [slug] => 
            [status] => 1
            [ktw_course_id] => 5
            [ktw_country_id] => 2
            [ktw_city_id] => 5
            [ktw_timeslot_id] => 0
            [ktw_training_mode_id] => 3
            [ktw_currency_id] => 6
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 
            [course] => jquery
            [country] => kuwait
            [city] => dubai
            [workshop_dates_id] => 7
            [start_date] => 2014-11-04
            [end_date] => 2015-01-05
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [price] => 900
            [discount] => 13
            [early_bird_date] => 2014-11-26
            [timing] => 
            [batch] => 
            [slug] => 
            [status] => 0
            [ktw_course_id] => 5
            [ktw_country_id] => 1
            [ktw_city_id] => 2
            [ktw_timeslot_id] => 0
            [ktw_training_mode_id] => 1
            [ktw_currency_id] => 1
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 2014-11-14 14:34:29
            [course] => jquery
            [country] => india
            [city] => vizag
            [workshop_dates_id] => 2
            [start_date] => 2014-11-28
            [end_date] => 2014-11-29
        )
```

But i need like this(all workshop_dates has to come for the particular workshop_id in array)

```
array(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [price] => 1300
            [discount] => 13
            [early_bird_date] => 2014-12-30
            [timing] => 
            [batch] => 
            [slug] => 
            [status] => 0
            [ktw_course_id] => 5
            [ktw_country_id] => 1
            [ktw_city_id] => 4
            [ktw_timeslot_id] => 0
            [ktw_training_mode_id] => 2
            [ktw_currency_id] => 1
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 2014-11-25 10:16:58
            [course] => jquery
            [country] => india
            [city] => hyderabad

            [workshop_dates] => array ( [0]

                                  [start_date] => 2014-12-30
                                  [end_date] => 2014-12-31

                                [1]
                                  [start_date] => 2014-11-28 
                                  [end_date] => 2014-12-29
                                 [2]
                                  [start_date] => 2014-11-28
                                    [end_date] => 2014-12-30
                                )

)
```

i want it as associative  array, one course may have multiple workshops and the same time it may have multiple dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use 2 query for this

first get the Work shop and base on workshop it get the workshop_dates

then using foreach you can make a associative array.